# How can I check if signal present in object?

Tags: c++, qt

I can't find a way to do it with a build-in way like `someObject->signalPresent(SomeSignal)`. Maybe I missed something. I know that I can do this in C++ using SFINAE, but there should be same ability to do that in QT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [QMetaObject::indexOfSignal()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#indexOfSignal). Code using it could look like:

```
if (someQObject->metaObject()->indexOfSignal("someSignal(QString)") != -1) {
    // has signal
    ...
} else {
    // doesn't have signal
    ...
}
```

Note the requirements regarding signature normalization described in the documentation, e.g. `"someSignal(const QString&)"` won't work.